# how to get contacts using address book API in ios programming?

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I have a question. I am new to this ios programming. I am doing an app which is basically similar to the address book in iphone. I need to get all the contacts from the address book and show them in table view. Can anyone please help me how to get the contacts using address book Api? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Post the code of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read and follow Apple's [Address Book Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html). Then come back here with specific questions if you encounter a problem.

Comment: @Mark Adams: I was already able to solve my problem with displaying contacts in  my table view in my app.Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi what you say is correct.This for launching the addressbook from our native app.Now i have one requirement that is i want to see the first,last name and email address and phone number in address book table.Can you please let me know how to customize the address book display order.